# Linking with conda version of yaml-cpp

Tags: linker, yaml-cpp

I am working on CentOS7 with devtoolset-10 activated:

```
scl enable devtoolset-10 bash
```

Also working in a newly created conda environment

```
conda create -n test-yaml-cpp python=3.10 yaml-cpp=0.7.0
conda activate test-yaml-cpp
```

I am trying to compile a very simple program using yaml-cpp called test.cpp

```
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>
#include <iostream>
int main (void){
    YAML::Emitter out;
    out << "Hello, World!";
    std::cout << "Here's the output YAML:\n" << out.c_str();
    return 0;
}
```

but linking fails, I don't understand why:

```
g++ -o test -I/local/home/dagnic/anaconda3/envs/test-yaml-cpp/include -L/local/home/dagnic/anaconda3/envs/test-yaml-cpp/lib test.cpp -lyaml-cpp

/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/ld: /tmp/cc9sE2ck.o: in function `YAML::operator<<(YAML::Emitter&, char const*)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN4YAMLlsERNS_7EmitterEPKc[_ZN4YAMLlsERNS_7EmitterEPKc]+0x43): undefined reference to `YAML::Emitter::Write(std::string const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I added nothing more in the environment variables.

I tried with a self-compiled and installed version of yaml-cpp 0.7.0 and I have no linking problem

```
g++ -o test -I/opt/3rd-party/yaml-cpp/include -L/opt/3rd-party/yaml-cpp/lib64 test.cpp -lyaml-cpp
```

**EDIT 1**: I fix the arguments order when calling g++ but it did not help.

**EDIT 2**: step to reproduce using a docker image from conda

```
docker run -i -t conda/miniconda3-centos7 /bin/bash

conda install -c conda-forge yaml-cpp
yum update -y
yum install -y centos-release-scl-rh
yum install -y devtoolset-10
export PATH=/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/bin:$PATH
# or scl enable devtoolset-10 bash
g++ -o test -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib test.cpp -lyaml-cpp
```

gives

```
/opt/rh/devtoolset-10/root/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/ld: /tmp/cc22r2Wj.o: in function `YAML::operator<<(YAML::Emitter&, char const*)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN4YAMLlsERNS_7EmitterEPKc[_ZN4YAMLlsERNS_7EmitterEPKc]+0x43):undefined reference to `YAML::Emitter::Write(std::string const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why:

Because your link command line is *wrong*. Try this one instead:

```
g++ -o test ... test.cpp -lyaml-cpp
```

To understand why the order of libraries and sources (or objects) on command line matters, read [this](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking).

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help.